# DialogFragment - Get width of dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to get the width of a `DialogFragment` on runtime, I've tried two methods which failed.

First: inside `onCreateDialog` after the dialog has been created

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    ...
    ...
    AlertDialog dialog =  builder.create();
    width = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width;
    return dialog;
}
```

`width` was set to -1

Second:

```
public void onStart() {
    width = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().width;
}
```

`width` was set to -2

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10118459/2553526 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18272220/2553526

Comment: @FaisalAli those methods seem to apply to Activity and not to Fragment objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using a `ViewTreeObserver` set in `onCreateDialog`