# Why I get the 0 value when using the imageView.getWidth()

Tags: android

I want  get the width value from the `imageView` object but when I run the following code It returns a `0` value. Why I  get the `0` value when using the `imageView.getWidth()`? How can I solve this problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
 super.onCreate(bundle);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
 Integer i = imageView.getWidth();
 textView.setText(i.toString());
    }}
```

Comment: That's because the layout traversal hasn't happened at that stage yet, how to fix that really depends on why you want to know, i.e. what you want to do with it.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android  
And here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268915/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returning-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply read the width of the ImageView in it's post method like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Integer i = imageView.getWidth();
                textView.setText(i.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The post callback is executed once all the ImageView's lifecycle methods are called, which means the whole view is already measured, therefore you have a proper width of the view.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can either move the call to view.post() or to activity.onPostResume(). At this stage the view should be fully initialized.

Answer (score -1):

It's very possible than on create the view hierarchy isn't inflated yet, so the view's dimension have not yet been set. I would move this call to a later stage of the activity lifecycle, maybe to `onResume()`.